# Excluding data sets in R

Tags: r, survey

I have some people in my data who don't fulfill the requirements that were necessary to complete my survey (too old and too young). How do I exclude them from my data since I can't use theirs?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. In general you would just `subset()` the data based on whatever criteria you want.

Comment: `library(dplyr) filter(data, age > x & age < y)`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

Data <- Data %>%
  filter(age > 15 & age < 100)
```

Ben